# For the probability triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \Bbb{P})$, a random variable $X$, and a function $g$, is $g(X)$ automatically measurable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, examples-counterexamples

For the probability triple $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \Bbb{P})$, a random variable $X: \Omega \to D$, and an arbitrary function $g: D \to E$, is $g \circ X$ also measurable and thus a random variable? I think the answer is no and there is a counterexample showing when this is not the case. I wouldn't know what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not true, if we assume the axiom of choice. Let your probability triple simply consist of the standard Lebesgue triple on $[0,1]$. Let $X:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ simply be the identity, i.e. $X(t)=t$. Let $V$ be your favourite non-measurable set, and define $g:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ by
$$g(t)=\begin{cases}1&t\in V\\ 0 &t\notin V
\end{cases}.$$
Thus $g$ is non-measurable ($g^{-1}(1)=V$), and $g\circ X=g$.